# JAXB: an element with textual content and attributes, generating classes with XJC

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

Recently I have faced a problem which seems to be very common: how to represent an XML element with attributes and simple textual content, like this:

```
<elem attr="aval">elemval</elem>
```

using JAXB.

I've found many advices on how to do this, but every one of these advices involves manual editing of binding classes.

I have a set of schemas and I use XJC to convert these schemas to Java classes. However, it seems that it produces wrong code, i.e. it does not generate methods to set plain content, there are methods for setting attributes only.

Is it possible to fix this behavior of XJC? Extensive googling didn't help on this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an XML schema that defines the XML structure for you use case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="elem">
        <complexType>
            <simpleContent>
                <extension base="string">
                    <attribute name="attr" type="string" />
                </extension>
            </simpleContent>
        </complexType>
    </element>

</schema>
```

Generating a JAXB model from this XML schema will result in the following class:

```
package forum12859885;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "elem")
public class Elem {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "attr")
    protected String attr;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getAttr() {
        return attr;
    }

    public void setAttr(String value) {
        this.attr = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is very strange. I have exactly the same schema up to the namespace prefix, and I'm certain that XJC generated a class without `getValue` and `setValue` methods... I've tested this now on my own computer and it worked successfully. I will try this again in two days, maybe I have missed something. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it was my fault. Just checked my schema, it had in fact `complexContent` instead of `simpleContent` inside `complexType` specification. Seems that this was the problem; changed it to `simpleContent`, and it worked like a charm. Thank you again, I'll accept your answer.